# How to use 'assert_enqueued_email_with' on rails 7

Tags: email, testing, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to following the documentation:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/TestHelper.html#method-i-assert_enqueued_email_with

My normal code is:

```
UserMailer.with(website_id: @LastWebsite_id, subject: @subject, body: @Body).send_mail_to_subscriptions.deliver_later
```

The following code that appear on the documentation works well:

```
assert_enqueued_emails 3
```

My test code (the code where i have problems is):

```
assert_enqueued_email_with UserMailer, :send_mail_to_subscriptions, args: {website_id: lastWebsiteId, subject: randomSubject, body: randomBody}
```

Appear the following error:

```
No enqueued job found with {:job=>ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob, :args=>["UserMailer", "send_mail_to_subscriptions", "deliver_now", {:params=>{:website_id=>"310450396", :subject=>"AS9VZRJEuXNZ5ie", :body=>"QpNqUrwcCuXMXaS"}, :args=>[]}], :queue=>"default"}
```

```
{"job_class"=>"ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob", "job_id"=>"27f4046a-aace-495b-911b-991e44d278e8", "provider_job_id"=>nil, "queue_name"=>"default", "priority"=>nil, "arguments"=>["UserMailer", "send_mail_to_subscriptions", "deliver_now", {"params"=>{"website_id"=>310450396, "subject"=>"AS9VZRJEuXNZ5ie", "body"=>"QpNqUrwcCuXMXaS", "_aj_symbol_keys"=>["website_id", "subject", "body"]}, "args"=>[], "_aj_ruby2_keywords"=>["params", "args"]}], "executions"=>0, "exception_executions"=>{}, "locale"=>"en", "timezone"=>"UTC", "enqueued_at"=>"2023-04-04T04:24:01Z", :job=>ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob, :args=>["UserMailer", "send_mail_to_subscriptions", "deliver_now", {:params=>{:website_id=>310450396, :subject=>"AS9VZRJEuXNZ5ie", :body=>"QpNqUrwcCuXMXaS"}, :args=>[]}], :queue=>"default", :priority=>nil}
```

I expected that pass the test successfully

Comment: For one, I see that your `website_id` is a string in the first output, and an integer in the second. Maybe that's where the mismatch is.

Comment: Thanks for the response i added a .to_i but still the error, thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [vladpisanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4028239/vladpisanov)

The following code works:

```
assert_enqueued_email_with UserMailer, :send_mail_to_subscriptions, args: {website_id: lastSubscription.website_id, subject: randomSubject, body: randomBody}
```

The data of website_id, should be send exactly like you use, not a equivalent. Thanks